# How to use angualr2 js with keystone cms?

Tags: node.js, angular, keystonejs

I installed angular2 in node_module, but as node_module is not static directory I can not use links of angular and its dependencies on html page.

what could be the proper way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy it somewhere in public folder, for example: js/vendor/...

This is usual way, otherwise you can break your application on `npm update`